# Problems installing Ime4 and ggplot2 on R 2.15.2

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I am having difficulty installing the lme4 and ggplot packages

I've tried to install them by selecting a CRAN mirror (have tried several) and then selecting the packages, and have also tried the following;

```
install.packages("lme4",repos="http://r-forge.r-project.org")
```

and

```
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
```

but however I try to call these packages I get the warning message

```
package ‘lme4’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

or

```
package ‘ggplot2’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

the only answers I can find for problems installing these packages suggest upgrading R to the latest version, but I am using 2.15.2 which I believe is the most recent available.

Has anyone else had this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

thanks.

Lian

Comment: The first one doesn't work for me either, but `ggplot2` installs just fine. Are you sure the mirror you've set is working?

Comment: the r-forge build of `lme4` is currently broken, trying to fix it. Is the CRAN version good enough for you ... ?

Answer (score 5):

I was having the exact same problem. Here is what solved it for me:

For convenience I added a default cran mirror in my `Rprofile.site` file:

```
local({r <- getOption("repos")
   r["CRAN"] <- "http://cran.stat.sfu.ca/"
   options(repos=r)})
```

Then installing packages in this order works:

```
install.packages("Matrix")
install.packages("nlme")
install.packages("minqa")
install.packages("RcppEigen")
install.packages("lme4",repos="http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos")
install.packages("ggplot2", dependencies=TRUE)
```

Hope it works for you as well.

Comment: in principle `install.packages("lme4",repos=c("http://lme4.r-forge.r-project.org/repos",getOption("repos")["CRAN"]),depend=TRUE)` should simplify things slightly.

Comment: but for some reason my copy of lme4 needed Matrix to be installed independently first or else things would break (for ex, autocomplete would freeze Emacs/ESS when compiling completions for lme4). The rest I'm installing individually 'just in case.'  But, to be fair, I didn't try Ben's exact install command, so that might be just as good. :)

Comment: @ChristopherPoile my autocomplete freezes as well! is there an easy solution?

Comment: @Dualinity only what I described above. I also went back to an earlier version of R, which fixed everything. But then the newer version started working again. So to sum up: I know nothing. I wave incense at R and kill a chicken, that usually fixes things.  (To be fair, it's actually Emacs that is finicky, not R.)

Answer (score 0):

These packages should work fine, maybe try a few more mirrors, for example the one in Austria. Although there are packages who have been thrown of CRAN, e.g. the colorout package has been off CRAN for some time. The solution is to download the package from CRAN manually, and install locally.