# Installing ggplot on SolusOS

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've installed R and Rstudio on a netbook running SolusOS (Debian) and those installations seem to be working OK. However I've had no success with installing the R package ggplot2 .

I've tried the stock command from within R and in Rstudio of:

```
install.packages(“ggplot2”)
```

also:

```
install.packages(“ggplot2”, dependencies=TRUE)
```

both as user and with root privileges. But when I go to a mirror I get:

**Warning message:**

```
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package 'ggplot2' is not available
```

I've also set up a /data/Rpackages/ directory as recommended in http://www.r-bloggers.com/installing-r-packages/ but this has also not been successful.

If anyone has advice on what else to try or indeed to how remove and reinstall R and start again I would be grateful.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14663702/problems-installing-ime4-and-ggplot2-on-r-2-15-2

Comment: Also make sure you have these packages installes: reshape, plyr, round_any, grid, proto